# CSS - Make div's (display:inline-block) layout not change when shrinking screen

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div class='htmlCommentTable'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='firstDiv'>
            <img class='clickedFlame' src="image.png" />
        </div>
        <div class='secondDiv'>
            name <br /> first comment sample text here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>    
        <div class='firstDiv'>
            <img class='clickedFlame' src="image.png" />    
        </div>
        <div class='secondDiv'>
            name <br /> second comment sample text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
    .htmlCommentTable {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .firstDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 90px;
    }

    .secondDiv {
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .row {
        width: 100%;
     }
```

Each row should have a 90px image (firstDiv) with another div beside it.

Cuurently, if I shrink the screen small enough so that it reaches the text inside secondDiv, then secondDiv goes below firstDiv rather than staying beside firstDiv.

How do I make it so that the div beside the 90px div (secondDiv) has a width of 100% of what is left inside the row (the row's width is 100%, the secondDiv's width should be 100%-90px - 90px is the width of firstDiv).
I need it so that when I shrink the screen / browser, the firstDiv's width remains at 90px and the secondDiv's width remains at 100%-90px, and only the height of the div increases (and secondDiv remains beside firstDiv, it doesn't go below firstDiv) if the screen becomes so small that the text inside secondDiv needs to be on more than one line.

Is it possible to do what I want? I tried giving secondDiv a width of 100% but that just puts secondDiv below firstDiv rather then beside firstDiv.

Comment: Take a look at `flexbox` http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using CSS tables as follows:

```css
.htmlCommentTable {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
}
.firstDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.secondDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.firstDiv img {
    display: block;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/dFCa8/

Apply `display: table` to each `.row` and for the two child elements `.firstDiv` and `.secondDiv` apply `display: table-cell`.

The first cell has a fixed width of 90px, and the second cell will fill the rest of the container width.

Being a table, the two child elements will always remain on a single line.

This will work in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/Joshuasm32/6p2Vd/) code to row and your problem should be fixed.  :)

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: hidden;
```

Also, if you want to add a [neat overflow effect](http://jsfiddle.net/Joshuasm32/6p2Vd/1/), you could use this code:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: hm, but I need it so that secondDiv's height increases and all the text inside secondDiv shows even if the user makes the screen smaller. When I used the CSS provided, it did not resize secondDiv, instead, secondDiv just stayed it's same size and the text got cut off as I made the screen smaller. I need it so that the text goes on a new line but the div remains in the same place.. you get what I mean?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood you. Marc Audet's answer is would be the best solution for this scenario.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use floats. Read up on them. Highly useful.

Coming back to your question:

1) http://jsfiddle.net/V2SGx/

```
.firstDiv {
    float: left;
}
```

Most likely that's all you want and need.

2) http://jsfiddle.net/V2SGx/1

```
.secondDiv {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

In case you never want for any text from secondDiv to get under firstDiv. Just set proper margin on .secondDiv. All asuming you know how wide .firstDiv will now and always be.

Comment: This (mine) answer just received the only down-vote in the whole thread - waging on the small chance that its author will read this comment, an explanation/suggestion to improve my answer would be warmly welcomed. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple and clean solution: background image.
You simply apply the image as a background on the left and indent the text 90px using `padding-left`.
see the [CodePen example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cfhgy).

I changed your html a bit for more semantic code, getting rid of unuseful divs. Of course, this example will work with your html structure as well.